# Any useful link for integrating Spring and openAM

Tags: spring, spring-security, openam, opensso

We are developing a simple demo web application where we have to use spring and openAM to consume SAML.Anybody has any idea or links on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty good and recent article on OpenAM wiki:

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+with+Spring+Security+SAML

Answer (score 1):

Check the links given below. Those might help.

[OpenAM Spring Security Integration](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+Spring+Security+Integration)

[Single Sign On (SSO) for Web applications using OPENAM](http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/03/sso-for-java-or-net-web-based.html)

[Integrating JSF web application with Openam using Spring Saml Extension](http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/06/integrating-jsf-web-applicataion-with.html)

[openam-integration-with-spring-security](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/128308-openam-integration-with-spring-security)

[Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/)

Comment: Thansk a lot for sharing the info.actually i need to implement openAM as a service provider and consume the response from identity provider.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need OpenAM as a service provider? If there is already an SAMLv2 Identity Provider you can use Spring Security SAML extension directly, as it's implementing a SAMLv2 Service Provider.

Comment: Thalmayer:
Thanks,we are developing a simple demo app(might be spring or simple servlet,where we have a SAML reponse with us.We need to consume and validate this using openAM API.Any suggestions onto which api to use.